# RailsAdmin - hidden form fields and labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Using RailsAdmin. I have a Post model and a User model. Each post belongs to a user.

I use the following code to get RailsAdmin to handle the association for me and automatically set the user_id when a Post is created:

```
  config.model Post do 
    edit do
      field :user_id do
        # use a form_field instead of the default drop-down
        partial :form_field
        # hide the input
        view_helper :hidden_field
        # set the value to current_user.id
        def value
          bindings[:view]._current_user.id
        end
      end 
    end
  end
```

This code works, it sets the user_id to that of the current_user and it also hides the form_field (the html input) from view so that user is not even aware that it is being set on their behalf.

There is one small problem though. Whilst I'm able to hide the form_field, I can't hide it's associated label (i.e. the label that reads "User" which appears next to the input) - which means my users see this:

[image]

As you can see, there is a label "User" with an empty space next to it, and the word "Required" underneath.

Is there anyway to hide an input's associated label too (and not just the input itself) so that it's not confusing to the user?  Is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found a working solution:

```
  field :user_id do
    view_helper :hidden_field

    # I added these next two lines to solve this
    label ""
    help ""

    partial :form_field
    def value
      bindings[:view]._current_user.id
    end
  end
```

Not ideal, but it works

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into the same obstacle and after some trial and error (and tips from the rails_admin group) arrived at a slight alternative:

```
config.model Library do
  edit do 
    field :user_id do
      # This hides the field label
      label :hidden => true
      # This hides the help field *yuk*
      help ""
      def value 
        bindings[:view]._current_user.id 
      end
      # This hides the field input 
      view_helper do
        :hidden_field
      end
    end
  end 
  field :name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this feature is added to `rails_admin` already and no need a workaround solution for this. You can do it as the following

```
  config.model Post do 
    edit do
      field :user_id do
        # This hides everything related with this field
        hide
        # You still need to set this value of course
        def value
          bindings[:view]._current_user.id
        end
      end 
    end
  end
```